# Liquibase multiple changelog execution

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

I'm using `SpringLiquibase` for liquibase configuration, below configuration works fine with single changelog file (sql formatted)

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class LiquibaseConfiguration {

  @Inject
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean
  public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    log.info("################## Entering into liquibase #################");
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:schema/update-schema-01.sql");
    // Configure rest of liquibase here...
    // ...
    return liquibase;
  }
}
```

In my application, i may need to run `more than one changelog` files and i couldn't make such execution,
I tried to feed multiple changelogs as follows,

> liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:schema/update-schema-01.sql");
>
> liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:schema/update-schema-02.sql");

the last one changelog file alone getting executed.

> liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:schema/*.sql");

Getting error as  `liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: java.io.IOException: Found 2 files that match classpath:schema/*.sql`

Please suggest a way to includeAll changelogs here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the possible solution: you can create the main changelog, which will [includes](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/include.html) other changelogs as much as you wish. And in the `SpringLiquibase` object you will set only one main liquibase changelog.

For example, assume you have 2 changelog files: `one-changelog.xml` and `two-changelog.xml` and you need to run the both. I suggest you to create one more file `main-changelog.xml` and include in it `one-changelog.xml` and `two-changelog.xml` files like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">

    <include file="one.xml"/>
    <include file="two.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And set `main-changelog.xml` file as changelog for `SpringLiquibase`.

As result, you will have 2 separate changelog files.

Comment: You meant to put all other change logs content into one log and use it ?

Comment: this is good suggestion, for my case am using sql formatted changelogs, i think i can have main changelog as xml and the including change logs in sql. i will try that.

Comment: Yes, you can include sql files in the same way

Comment: It works by having `<includeAll path="schema/"/>` inside of main-changelog.xml, thank you so much :-)