# Springboot external library Liquibase migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, module, liquibase

I have an external SpringBoot commons library (built as a `jar`) and a main project that includes it.

The external library requires a set of default database tables. For this, I have set up  Liquibase. The main project also makes us of Liquibase. Both projects have different changelog files. Suppose one is named `library.xml` and the other `main.xml`. All database and Liquibase properties are configured in the main project (as well as `spring.liquibase.change-log=main.xml`).

The library has a single property: `spring.liquibase.change-log=library.xml`.

How can I tell Liquibase "Run both `library.xml` and `main.xml`"? I suppose there is something I need to configure in the library project, since the main application should use it as is (simply by importing and using it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Liquibase multiple changelog execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56292517/liquibase-multiple-changelog-execution)

Comment: @xerx593 not really, since it involves adding logic in the main project. Since I am making a standalone library, it should work by default, without additional logic.

Comment: Ok... Seems it is possible/no problem to have multiple `@Bean SpringLiquibase` (https://dev.to/vladonemo/splitting-liquibase-changelong-no-problem-2a4l) ..define(&test) it in your "lib" (standalone). In "main" ensure to pick it up (component scan) or "auto configure" "lib".

Comment: @xerx593 please make it an answer. This has fixed my issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To combine/structure our (liquibase) change logs, we can:

1. <del>Use ([liquibase](/questions/tagged/liquibase)) [`include`  "attribute" (et al.)](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/include.html).</del> (I'd still prefer this!)
2. (With [spring](/questions/tagged/spring)) Define *multiple* `@Bean SpringLiquibase`s:

   - As simple as shown [here](https://dev.to/vladonemo/splitting-liquibase-changelong-no-problem-2a4l) (adjusted copy below).
   - or (also deactivating, but) utilizing [spring-boot auto configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java)...

---

##### Spring-Boot (2.7.5) solution:

(main project) `application.properties`:

```properties
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/main.xml
# many more with same prefix ...
lib.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/library.xml
# according for lib.liquibase.* ...
```

Main/Config class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(/* scanBasePackages = "com.example.lib" */)
// We need/want these:
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LiquibaseProperties.class)
public class Demo {

  @Bean // "main" liquibase: 
  // when order matters: @DependsOn("liquibaseLib") 
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.liquibase") // !
  public SpringLiquibase liquibase( 
      ObjectProvider<DataSource> dataSource,
      @LiquibaseDataSource ObjectProvider<DataSource> liquibaseDataSource,
      LiquibaseProperties properties) {
    return liqui(dataSource, liquibaseDataSource, properties);
  }

  @Bean // lib liquibase:
  @ConfigurationProperties("lib.liquibase")
  public SpringLiquibase liquibaseLib(
      ObjectProvider<DataSource> dataSource,
      /* alternatively: @MyVeryCustomDataSource ... */
      @LiquibaseDataSource ObjectProvider<DataSource> liquibaseDataSource,
      LiquibaseProperties properties) {
    return liqui(dataSource, liquibaseDataSource, properties);
  }

  // pstvm...

  private SpringLiquibase liqui(ObjectProvider<DataSource> dataSource,
      ObjectProvider<DataSource> liquibaseDataSource, LiquibaseProperties properties) {
    // trick: Don't use LiquibaseConfiguration as `@Configuration/Bean`
    // , it is not "repeatable" (in regards of liquibase execution;(
    // , but rather as a "utility object"/factory:
    LiquibaseConfiguration helpr = new LiquibaseConfiguration(properties);
    return helpr.liquibase(dataSource, liquibaseDataSource);
  }
}
```

Header (package+imports) of Demo.java:

> `package com.example.app;import javax.sql.DataSource; import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase; import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider; import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication; import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication; import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseConfiguration; import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseDataSource; import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties; import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties; import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;`

[See Also.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseProperties.java)

---

##### Simple Solution

...as shown by [2](https://dev.to/vladonemo/splitting-liquibase-changelong-no-problem-2a4l):

> ```java
> import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
> import javax.sql.DataSource;
>
> @Configuration // scanned/imported/used by "main" !
> public class MultipleLiquiaseConfiguration {
>
>     @Bean
>     public SpringLiquibase liquibaseLib(DataSource dataSource) { // !
>         SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
>         liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
>         liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:library.xml"); // !
>         return liquibase;
>     }
>
>     @Bean
>     // when order matters: @DependsOn("liquibaseLib")
>     public SpringLiquibase liquibaseMain(DataSource dataSource) { // !
>         SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
>         liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
>         liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:main.xml"); // !
>         return liquibase;
>     }
> }
> ```

---

Regarding:

> The library has a single property...

I *hope* it is a *test* property;)!